# React - make a restapi request for a single object not an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request

I'm relatively new to react and therefore a somewhat stupid question.

I am currently writing a small webapp in react in which I want to make an api request. The json I get back looks like this:

```
{
 "something": {
 "value": "#001",
 "clean": "001"
 },
 "name": {
 "value": "Paco",
 "distance": 610
 }
}
```

and my code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <h2>Subline</h2>

      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.thecolorapi.com/id?hex=441212")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <li>{item.name.value}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

And I am aware that I am using a list here, even though I just want the Obejct "name.value" (=> in my example: Paco)  in my application.
But with the code just shown I get the error "TypeError: data.map is not a function" and if I understand correctly the .map () function is only for arrays.
So my question is what do I use for a single object? (if i assume correctly at least that it is an object)

tl;dr: i want to get the name value (e.g. Paco) in my app, whether as a separate component or as a variable

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned above, it's an object. So you just need to treat it as an object too. So in the state, you write

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
```

Its an empty object at first, since you will change the 'data' with an object.

Then don't use map unless it's an array.

example

```
<p>{data.name.value}</p>
```

You are using

```
<ul>
  <li>
```

Its preferred to use it only for array. If it an object, just use simple h1 tag or p or something like that.

But you want to change the data to an array, even though its only 1 object of array, your approach is good to go. Just push your object to an array.

```
fetch("https://www.thecolorapi.com/id?hex=441212")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const testarray = [];
    testarray.push(data);
    setData(testarray);
  })
```

Insert it first to array, then set it to state. In the state, you use

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert object to array to use map function.
You can use Object.values() for your code like this:

```
{Object.values(data).map((item) => (
    <li>{item.value}</li>
 ))}
```

There are Object.keys() and Object.values() function in Javascript to convert object to array.

The first one returns array of keys in object and the second one returns array of values in object.

```
data = {
    "something": {
        "value": "#001",
        "clean": "001"
    },
    "name": {
        "value": "Paco",
        "distance": 610
    }
};

Object.keys(data) = [
    "something", 
    "name"
];

Object.values(data) = [
    {
        "value": "#001",
        "clean": "001"
    },
    {
        "value": "Paco",
        "distance": 610
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use object desctructuring to extract only value from 'value' property nested in 'name' property of your response, then your state will be just string with this one name (array state is not needed because your useEffect hook is called only on mounting this component, so this array won't have more than one element)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <h2>Subline</h2>

      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

function MyComponent() {

  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.thecolorapi.com/id?hex=441212")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({name:{value}}) => {
        setData(() => value);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
        <li>{data}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```